# wordpress 3.9 remote token auth

Tags: authentication, remote-login

I came across the following code here

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Remote Login
Description: Log into the site with creds that work on remote site (as defined in plugin). The remote site must have XML-RPC enabled.
Author: Kailey Lampert
Author URI: http://kaileylampert.com/

    THIS IS NOT COMPLETE - DO NOT USE IN PRODUCTION

    The remote site (defined below in $server) is the "master" site.
    All active users on the master site can log in this site with their "master" credentials

    "this site" means the site this plugin is installed on :)

    When they log in a "ghost" users is created. This user is not destroyed. Ideally they'd self-delete after some amount of time to make sure we don't have unneeded users sticking around... 
    If the user already exists, a new password will be created each time it is logged in.

    "ghost" users are always admins, even if the master user isn't. This needs to be fixed.
*/

new Remote_Login();

class Remote_Login {

    //this should be your remote site
    var $server = 'demo.trepmal.com'; //has public credentials demo:demo for testing
        //demo.trepmal.com resets periodically, so the XML-RPC option may be off by the time you use this
        //that's a good thing, else anyone could log into this site with demo:demo

    function __construct() {
        add_filter( 'authenticate', array( &$this, 'auth' ), 10, 3 );
    }

    function auth( $user, $username, $password ) {
        if ($username == 'demo') {
            //if username is 'demo'. may change this to check for special username prefix or something...

            //try it against remote server
            if ( ! $this->remote_login_check( $this->server, $username, $password )) return $user;

            //if it worked, setup new user
            $username = 'prefix_'.$username; //prefix the "ghost" user's username
            $password = wp_generate_password( 16, true );

            //if user already exists, change the password
            if ( $user_id = username_exists( $username ) ) {
                wp_set_password( $password, $user_id );
                $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
            } else {
            //else create the user
                $user_id = wp_create_user( $username, $password );
            }
            //authenticate them
            $user = wp_authenticate( $username, $password );
            //make sure it has correct role
            $user->set_role('administrator'); //we should be fetching the "master" user's role, and using that instead of always administrator
        }
        return $user;
    }

    function remote_login_check( $server, $username, $password ) {

        require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-includes/class-IXR.php' );
        $client = new IXR_Client( esc_url( $server ) .'/xmlrpc.php' );

        //test query, see if creds work
        //todo: instead of wp.getOptions, get user so we can give the "ghost" a better role
        if ( ! $client->query( 'wp.getOptions', '', $username, $password, 'blog_title' ) ) {  

            //return $client->getErrorMessage();
            return false;

            echo 'Error occured during the request.<br />' .
                $client->getErrorCode() . ': ' . $client->getErrorMessage();

        } else {

            //return $client->getResponse();
            return true;
            printer( $client->getResponse() );
        }        

    }

}


if ( ! function_exists( 'printer') ) {
    function printer( $input ) {
        echo '<pre>' . print_r( $input, true ) . '</pre>';
    }
}
```

[source](https://gist.github.com/trepmal/2968439)

Currently the remote authentication is token based.  So when the user logs in a token is generated validating the user.  I haven't come across any good documentation in implementing remote authentication with Wordpress. Is there any good code samples or tutorials in doing this.

Comment: What exactly are your requirements? What had you tried? Which "bad" documentation had you seen (I am not sure if this includes the gist you quote) and what was lacking in it?

Comment: When a user hits a page or post that requires authentication it will redirect to another domain if the user logins in on that domain it will redirect back to the wordpress site and have the ability to browse the page or post.